# Append Meta Tag in Html - Win Phone 8 - C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, append

Im building a Windows Phone 8 App which has a webbrowser. I would like append a meta tag inside the head tag on the page which is shown in my webbrowser.

I've tried it with this but it gives me a System Exception Error 80020101.

```
WebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", @"document.getElementsByTagName(""head"")[0].appendChild(""<meta 
name=""viewport"" content=""user-scalable=no"">"")");
```

I was told to try it with this code below but I dont think you can use that in C#.

```
link=document.createElement('link');
link.href='href';
link.rel='rel';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure this property is set on your webBrowser object:

```
webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
```

Then you should also probably check your javascript method in the desktop IE11 debugger, whether the code actually works as expected. Adding new meta tags into your page might not be that easy.